Ways to disable or limit Wordpress postmeta caching
I've been dealing with a helping out on a 3rd party website that is regularly hitting memory limits for a while now. To start with the site would only run at all with a 1GB memory limit. It moved to a host that would only allow 512MB and so we had to try and figure out what was going on.
After digging in we found that loading posts in the cartflows plugin was retrieving a huge amount of data from the postmeta table. The was primarily caused by the Beaver Builer editor using postmeta to store page revisions. By clearing out previous revisions we were atleast able to get the site running, even though it was still loading ~150MB of data from postmeta. (We have added a mini plugin from GitHub designed to regularly clear out these revisions which claims to be written for "potato hosts with low limits", although I wouldn't really consider 512MB a low limit)
However, we now have a memory issue in a certain part of the site where it just so happens to be triggering more than 500MB of memory usage.
I decided to look into the cartflows plugin again to see if I could manually limit the metadata being retrieved in an attempt to get this query down in size, and hopefully reduce the overall memory usage.
It turns out that the plugin is using get_posts, and already specifies a meta_query option to limit metadata to just a single key, which should retrieve a very small amount of data.
Looking more into it, it appears that even though the plugin is trying to do the right thing, the get_posts system in Wordpress is calling update_postmeta_cache, which blindly pulls all metadata for the relevant posts in order to refresh an in-memory cache (basically an array) of all post meta.
Is there anything that can be done to address this? Arguably Beaver Builder shouldn't be storing large amounts of data in postmeta but I obviously can't remove its active data without breaking the site, and Wordpress blindly dumping all metadata for posts into a cache array is using up several hundred MB of ram even though the plugins requesting posts don't ask for it.
I don't know if it's even possible to disable metadata caching or if the entire system is built on the assumption that all metadata is accessed through the cache. Even trying to hack the metadata cache manually to ignore beaverbuilder entries could stop the page editor from working if it assumes the relevant metadata can be accessed via the cache.

Nice investigation! That should be hackable I'd think but I'm not sure where to start. There aren't any hooks you can use to filter the automatically loaded postmeta from update_postmeta_cache, like the autoload flag in wp_options? Sounds like there ought to be, so worth a trac ticket or discussion if not..

And while you obviously want to keep the memory per request low, 512K does sound a bit small to me. I'd be tempted to pay your new host for more memory too even if you can solve this problem.

note that a vanilla WP install will use ~15-20mb, 512mb is already worryingly large, and 256mb would be considered a heavy site. I'd edit your question to lead with how to prevent WordPress retrieving and caching post meta, but I'd also be mindful that questions about 3rd party plugins are offtopic here, you can't ask for help or about a 3rd party plugin such as cartflows, you'll have to take it up with their support.

Have you tried setting update_post_meta_cache to false in the queries

@Paul Yes I came across this earlier and it may have helped. Of course this meant modifying a 3rd party plugin that will revert if an update is installed. Does also appear that caching can be disabled entirely via a better method (functions.php or a custom plugin) but this may be a bit extreme.

I don't have full confirmation that they no longer see out of memory issues, but from logging the memory usage at shutdown it appears that this memory issue has likely been reduced by setting the following option in the get_posts call in cartflows:
'update_post_meta_cache' => false

Obviously this isn't ideal as a plugin update will reset this. I may look at using the parse_query hook to see if I can identify the cartflows request and set this flag via functions.php or a simple custom plugin.
It does identify a larger issue though that some plugins (looking at you Beaver Builder) use postmeta not for storing small flags or additional values, but for large blocks of data, sometimes several MB in size. By default Wordpress seems to assume that postmeta will be fairly small and caches all post meta for every post that is loaded, leading to a cache array that can be several 100MB in size. Beaver Builder exacerbates this by not only storing its "current" data structure in meta, but numerous previous revisions.
As the site grows, with more and more posts and revisions made, coupled with other plugins that may use get_posts to retrieve a decent sized list of posts, you have a site that start to need hundreds if not gigabytes of memory to successfully handle a request.
